# Issue with Chrome on loading jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I'm having some trouble with a simple jQuery animation in chrome. It happens when the browser is loaded the first time. The first div (id=rijbewijs), the top blue bar, that is animated sometimes get's skipped and doesn't appear at all.  I was thinking maybe chrome skips this because it's still busy loading the other images. It doesn't happen all the time, mainly when loading for the first time.

Other browsers I haven't noticed the bug, I see there where some problems in earlier versions of jQuery with the animate function, but that doesn't seem to be the same issue.

my code:

```
$('document').ready(function(){
     $('#rijbewijs').css({
        'left':'-600px'
      })

     $('#proefles, #tweeuurles').css({
        'left':'700px'
      });

    $('#main img').ready(function(){
            $('#headerBackground').show();
            $('#headerBackground, #main img').fadeIn(600,function(){
                $('#rijbewijs').delay(750).animate({
                    'left':'0'
                }, 500);

                $('#proefles').delay(1750).animate({
                    'left':'175'
                }, 500);

                $('#tweeuurles').delay(2500).animate({
                    'left':'209'
                }, 500);
            });
    });
});
```

see it here
http://www.rijschool-rijles.nl/in/amsterdam

Anybody a solution?

Comment: Unable to understand whats not working. I opened the link in chrome and two purple bars in the middle floated from right to left.

Comment: yes ! it floats the reverse way from them. i.e. left to right. Working good on my end. I am using chrome

Comment: Problem is that it works most of the times, but I've noticed that sometimes, maybe when the connection is slower it doesn't. I saw it both on my home as my work computer.

Comment: in that case, you can call the jquery function after the page loads fully by using `window.onload` property. But, it's working and there is no issue with the code for sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad: $('document') should be $(document).